# Selecting multiple sections and rows at a time in Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

In my tableview I have different number of sections and different number of rows in each section.

1. I want to select one section, for eg. if I select first section it should select all rows from that section. If I uncheck that section, it should uncheck all rows.
2. If I select all rows in a section, it should check the section header also, if I uncheck atleast one row in that section, it should uncheck section header.

I can select all rows if I select one section, its working but If I check all rows section header is not getting selected.

Its completely vice versa among sections and rows.

Please Can I get any help for this.

Answer (score 0):

case 1: when select on section header

run for loop to set the property of object (like strSelect=@"1"). set the checkmark image on that section and cell of that section.

case 2: selecting the cells.

on selecting any cell check that all object of that cell are selected or not.
if selected then then set the checkmark image on section and cells of that section

case 3 on deselecting the section header

run for loop to set the property of object (like strSelect=@"0"). set the uncheckmark image on that section and cell of that section.

for case 2 example

```
NSInteger sectionArrayCount= sectionArray.count;
NSInteger totalSelectedObject=0;
for (Item *obj in sectionArray)
{

    if ([obj.strSelectedQuantity isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        totalSelectedObject+=1;
    }
}

if (totalSelectedObject == sectionArrayCount)
{
    NSLog(@"all cells of that section are selected");
}
```

Comment: @Niting Singh: case 1 and 3 are working fine for me, can you check my code for case 2, or can i get some sample code for that doing. so that I can implement it, already I have been trying in possible ways to achieve it. so it can be helpful if i get some kind of code..

Comment: for case 2 when cell or object of section is selecting then run a loop for array of that section and check the count of selected object is equal to section array then that section is selected. example:  NSInteger sectionArrayCount= sectionArray.count;
    NSInteger totalSelectedObject=0;
    for (Item *obj in sectionArray)
    {
        
        if ([obj.strSelectedQuantity isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            totalSelectedObject+=1;
        }
    }
    
    if (totalSelectedObject == sectionArrayCount)
    {
        NSLog(@"all cells of that section are selected");
    }